# How to use data from a service in app-routing-module in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have a problem passing data from my service to my app-routing-module

Here is my service (sender service):

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SenderService {
  constructor() {}

  private DailyListID = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  SharedDailyListID = this.DailyListID.asObservable();

  setDailyListId(list) {
    this.DailyListID.next(list._id);
  }
}
```

and this is my app-routing-module:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

var mainListId = '619bcdef2888490b5867bcbe';
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: `/list/${mainListId}`, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'list/:id', component: HomeComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

I want the `mainListId` value in routing module to be `SharedDailyListID` from the `SenderService`. It must adhere to the `DailyListID` stream and change to it's emissions accordingly.

Comment: You'll have to write the redirect logic in you `app.component.ts` instead.

Comment: why not use a route guard ?

Answer (score 1):

try to use guard with navigate logic. in Guard u can use services